# session variable is comming out to be null after first request

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am facing a very weird situation. I have created a simple web app in which I log in with the index file then it goes to the servlet for validation and forwards to welcome jsp page ... from there I have two more links which connects to two different jsp pages. Now what happening is I have set the object containing username and password in the LoginServlet. Now when it forwards to welcome jsp I am able to retrieve the object but after that in every jsp I am getting session variable null. Though the same app is running fine on my friends eclipse.

I am using tomcat 8 and eclipse mars
Here is the login servlet

```
`LoginModel model = (LoginModel) request.getAttribute("login");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("loginmodel", model);
    System.out.println("uid "+model.getUid());
    LoginService lser = new LoginServiceImpl();
    int x = lser.login(model);
    if (x == 1) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome").forward(request, response);

    } else {
        response.getWriter().println("<h2>Login Id or Password invalid</h2>");
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

rd.include(request, response);
}
```

here is welcome page

```
<body>
<%LoginModel model=(LoginModel)session.getAttribute("loginmodel");
    out.print(model);
%>
${sessionScope.loginmodel};
<h2><a href="logout">LOGOUT</a></h2>
<section class="container">
    <div class="login">
<h2><a href="viewall">VIEW ALL</a></h2>
   <h2><a href="edit">EDIT</a></h2>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Here is edit jsp

```
<body>
<%LoginModel lm=(LoginModel)session.getAttribute("loginmodel");
    out.print(lm);
%>
<h2><a href="logout">LOGOUT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="welcome">HOME</a></h1><br><br>
<section class="container">
    <div class="login">
<form action="editjspcontroller">
<h3><p><label>Enter No</label></p></h3><p><input type="text" name="ppno" id="no"></p>
<p class="submit"><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with the given code.
You said the exact app can be run on your friend's machine.

- Check if you disabled cookies
- Use another browser to run your app.